# ViewData is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

inside controller I'm checking state of some property and based on that I want to send on the view some flag. I decide to use ViewData for data.

```
 if (model.MyProp == null)
 {
    ViewData["MyFlag"] = "yes"; // it doesn't need to be yes, basically if exist
 }
```

and inside razor view in embeded js script code

```
<script>
  if (ViewData["MyFlag"] != undefined) {
    alert('0');
  }
</script>
```

on page render firebug console report me error

> ReferenceError: ViewData is not defined

so what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `razor syntax(@)` to access `ViewData` inside `javascript`.

```
<script>
  if (@ViewData["MyFlag"] != undefined) {
    alert('0');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @user1765862, This is the answer.